# How to fix SSH on OSX?

Tags: ssh, osx, sshd

I have been able to connect to OSX machine using ssh client successfully for hours, but then it stops working and I `get connection refused`.

```
ps -ax | grep ssh
841 ttys004    0:00.00 grep ssh
```

Using dynamic IP and the IP is correct. I turned off and on "Remote Login", but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Does there need to be an SSH daemon running on OSX?

How to start it?

OSX 10.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no session connected to OSX, there will be no sshd process.
Try if this is working:

```
ssh localhost
```

If not:

```
systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

If it works, you've got network/firewall problem.

Comment: Yes, `ssh localhost` works and I now see the sshd daemon. So now I need to figure out the network issue. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, the router is not blocking port 22. Restarting it fixed the issue.